# AngularJS ngModel changes doesnt affect function calling

Tags: angularjs

By some reason, angularJS ngModel doesn't recognize changes when calling function.

Example:
On controller:

```
$scope.providers = [
    {id: 1, name:"bla"},
    {id: 2, name:"ble"},
    {id: 3, name:"bli"}
]


$scope.bla = function(some_id) {
    console.log(some_id); //undefined
}
```

On Html:

```
<select ng-model="provider.id" ng-options="provider.id as provider.name for provider in providers"/>

<a href ng-click="bla({{provider.id}})">go bla</a>
```

The strange thing is: When i inspect element on the `<a>`, I see ng-click="bla(some_id)". Then i click on it and come undefined on the function.

Comment: remove the curly braces `ng-click="bla(provider.id)"`

Comment: @MaxFichtelmann You should have posted that as the answer, mate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The curly braces are not needed (and are not evaluated) in expressions that are evaluated as javascript like ngClick, ngShow, ngClass etc.

Removing them will fix your issue:

```
ng-click="bla(provider.id)"
```